# Flutter error on updating Android Studio, Kotlin, Flutter, Dart plugins are incompatible with the new Android Studio version 4.0

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I just updated the Android Studio to 4.0, and now I am getting the errors in my IDE that  Kotlin, Flutter, Dart plugins are incompatible with the new Android Studio version 4.0, what's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to open Settings.
2. Look for `Plugins` in the tab bar.

   [image]

   You will see an option to update them and restart IDE, (I already did that, so it's not showing that option).
3. After updating, click on `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ....` in Android Studio toolbar.

   [image]
4. Run

   ```
   flutter clean
   ```

Comment: Good info. Andorid studio also warns before updating.

Answer (score 0):

How i fixed this:

1. Locate and open the idea.properties file in your Android/bin folder
2. Add idea.plugins.host=https://plugins.jetbrains.com to the file.
3. Save and close file
4. Relaunch Android Studio